# Why informatica fetches more records from source when source itself has less records

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have an issue in production env, one of the work flow is running more tgan one day and inserting records in to sql server db. It s just direct load mapping, there is no sq over ride as well. Monitor shows sq count as 7 million and inseting same no of records inyo target. But source db shows around 3 million records only. How can this be possible?

Comment: Usually when I see something different than the session, it's because I look somewhere else. Please go to the session log and look carefully at all the messages for the 'reader' thread that reads from this source (there may be more than one and they are named reader_1_1_1 and reader_1_1_2). Look at the exact database/server it reads from and copy the exact sql to management studio and confirm all are identical. After that: consider that the source is not stable as suggested elsewhere in this thread...

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the source qualifier is joining more than one table? A screenshot of the affected mapping pipeline and obfuscated logfile would help.

Another thought... given your job ran for a day, were there any jobs ran in that time to purge old records from the source table?

Answer (score 0):

Cases when I saw this kind of things happening:

1. There's a SQL Query override doing something different than I thought (eg. joining some tables)
2. I'm looking at a different source - verify the connections and make sure to check the same object on the same database at the same server the PowerCenter is connecting to.
3. It's a reusable session being executed multiple times by different workflows. In such case in workflow monitor it may happen that `Source/Target Statistics` will refer to another execution.